# Crystal Report is not Showing up when called in VB.net 2010

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, crystal-reports

I created a report in Crystal reports 2013 and am now trying to display that report within an application that I am writing in vb.net 2010.

The form displays fine except the viewer shows an error that reads:

"An error occurred during local report processing.  The definition of the report 'h:\reports\rptBookings.rpt' is invalid.  The report definition is not valid.  Details: Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 1. Position 1."

I have a form with a report viewer on it, and am trying to assign the report to the viewer so that when the form is shown the report will also get displayed.

Here is the code that I have set:

```
rvReports.LocalReport.ReportPath = "h:\reports\rptBookings.rpt"
```

Notes:
rvRepports is the report viewer

Comment: Show `ReportDIR`, where it is set.

Comment: Are you sure there is \ after the directory. Use `IO.Path.Combine` method to combine paths.

Comment: check on the report form to see if you have reports\rptBookings.rpt rather than rptBookings.rpt

Comment: coji: I don't understand what you mean.  I set the report filename and path in the code as shown in the question.

Comment: Ok.  I just realized the report viewer in vs 2010 is not crystal reports it's a microsoft control.  Where did the crystal reports viewer control go?